# Check if any cells had value change DataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to check if any value in any cells has been changed in `DataGridview` *(WinForms C#)* before I update the code in a button click.

To accomplish this task, I created a global boolean variable `gridCellChanged` and I set it to `true` in `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event.

```
private void GvTieredPricing_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   gridCellChanged = true;
}
```

And in the button event I check

```
private void btnUpdate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (gridCellChanged)
  {
     //execute my code
  }
}
```

This solution works for most of the time. However, if user changes value in Row 1, Column 1, `gridCellChanged` will be set to true. However, when user decides to revert the change and set the value to whatever it was the `gridCellChanged` will still get set to true and code will get executed in a button event.

How can I prevent this?

I have tried using `CellValueChanged` event. However, every time I load the grid on form load it takes me to that event and always sets my boolean variable to true even though there're has been no change to any cells.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you save the original as a viewstate and then compare the original viewstate with the current to see if they are the same or not?

Comment: I did thought about a similar approach where I insert the initial value in one list and new value in another and start comparing them. But it seems to much for a simple problem. Could you give me an example of a viewstate?

Comment: @Sam do a simple google search on `DataGridViewCellValueChanged` here is a link to get you started.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Is the DGV data bound?

Comment: @MethodMan, that was the first thing I have tried. I have explained in my code that I have an issue with that event. Thanks.

Comment: You should add this fact to your question. - After loading you can reset the flag yourself, no?

Comment: @TaW, the reason I didn't mentioned that is I don't populate the datagridview in a standard way. This project is using custom control that connects to DB and populates data. The reason I can't set the flag is I don't know when exactly that change is happening and if it's a valid change. If user A changes row 1, from 0 to 1 it's a change. But before submitting that change user A changes 1 back to 0, then this is no longer a change. My solution is considering this as a change.

Comment: Yes. Do you have an undo feature?

Comment: Then I think treating a reversed change as a change is pretty much standard.

Comment: In your case you **need** to compare original value to current value. For example save original value in `.Tag` property. In `CellEndEdit` event handler compare new value with original, if value is different - save cell in the List or Hashset. Then if user change value back to original you will remove cell from then List. In the update method just check if List of changes contains any cells

Comment: I was working on an answer which paralleled very closely to what Fabio said.  Instead of the `Tag` property, I used 2d array of object type to store the original values to check against, but the idea is the same either way.  Also, instead of `CellEndEdit`, I'd suggest `CellValueChanged` event handler - why? The handler for `CellEndEdit` works just fine, until you have a `CheckBoxColumn`.  That column will not behave as expected in `CellEndEdit` but works fine in `CellValueChanged`.